# Empty value in Mappings

Tags: amazon-cloudformation

In my Cloudformation template I want to use an empty value:

```
Mappings:
  DomainEnvironmentPrefix:
    stag:
      prefix: staging.
    prod:
      prefix:
```

I am getting this error and it's obvious what is causing the problem:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the ValidateTemplate operation: [/Mappings/DomainEnvironmentPrefix/prod/prefix] 'null' values are not allowed in templates

**Question**

How can I use an empty value in Cloudformation template's mapping?

Answer (score 2):

Just after I asked the question I realized that problem is not connected to Cloudformation but to YAML.

The empty value in YAML can be done using: `prefix: ""`